# R package development check, build, and install runtime is very slow (due to GitHub?)

Tags: r, github, r-package, cran

there. I am creating a Stan-based R package. I know that the `devtools::check(args = c('--as-cran'))` runtime (which involves compiling the C++ codes) is **slow**. In my case, it takes about 20 minutes. Fortunately, the `devtools::check_win_release()` and `devtools::build()` commands are quick in a few seconds.

However, I recently link the package to my GitHub repository for the version control. The differences are the additional `README.md` and `README.Rmd` files. And, I have added `^README\.Rmd$` and `^README\.md$` to `.Rbuildignore`. Now, I notice that the runtime for `devtools::check_win_release()` and `devtools::build()` becomes very slow. It will display the message "installing the package to process help pages" for quite a bit of time and then continue on.

What has caused this issue? Any comments? Thanks.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that using github or a readme would change the build process that much. Are you also ignoring the .git files? There's really not a lot of details here to say what's going on. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: So, that's my .Rbuildignore file.

Comment: ^myProj\.Rproj$ ^\.Rproj\.user$ ^LICENSE\.md$ ^data-raw$ ^\.travis\.yml$ ^\.DS_Store$ ^\.o$ ^\.so$ ^\.dll$ ^\.Rhistory$ ^README\.Rmd$ ^README\.md$

Comment: One execution message draws my attention: "saving partial Rd database (14m 25.4s)".

Comment: Are your documentation files large? Do you have long running examples? It’s really not fun to have to psychically  guess what might be going on. Maybe include a link to your repo?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have figured it out. (Nothing wrong with GitHub)

So, I changed the **documentation** for the **data**: I used to write as `@source \url{http://dx.doi.org/SOMETHING}`; however, `devtools::check_win_release()` suggests I use `@source \doi{SOMETHING}`; so I changed it.

Then, the issue occurs.
The building messages used to be like

```
✓  checking for file ‘*/DESCRIPTION’ ...
# ─  preparing ‘*’:
# ✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
# ─  cleaning src
# ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
# ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
# ─  building ‘*_*.tar.gz’
#
# [1] "*/*.tar.gz"
```

Now, it becomes (running slow for "installing the package to process help pages")

```
# ✓  checking for file ‘*/DESCRIPTION’ (611ms)
# ─  preparing ‘*’: (2.2s)
# ✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
# ─  cleaning src
# ─  installing the package to process help pages
# ─  saving partial Rd database (14m 25.4s)
# ─  cleaning src
# ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
# ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
# ─  building ‘*.tar.gz’
#
# [1] "*/*.tar.gz"
```

At last, I delete `@source` and just leave `@references`. The issue solved.